# Changing ascending sort to descending in MIPS assembly

Tags: sorting, assembly, linked-list, mips

I know that in c or java the quick fix to changing an ascending sort to descending would be to find the < or > somewhere and reverse it. But try as I might, I can't find the equivalent (or equivalent swap) to change this code that I've written to be descending instead of ascending. (Right now, it works perfectly in printing the linkedlist in ascending order). There's a fair 100 or so lines above what I've included that I cut out as they don't do the sort, but they assign values--so that isn't the problem. I feel like I'm just missing something obvious? Would the change be in the way I print or the way I insert or both? Any help would be appreciated.

```
loop_to_find_correct_spot:
    beqz $t0, if_current_node_next_equals_null
    l.s $f0, 0($t0)
    c.lt.s $f12, $f0
    bc1t if_current_node_does_not_equal_null

    or $t1, $t0, $zero
    lw $t0, 4($t0)

    j loop_to_find_correct_spot

if_current_node_next_equals_null:
    # link this node to the previous, $v0 = &(previous node)
    # copy address of the new node into the previous node
    sw $v0, 4($t1)

    # initalize the current node value to the passed in argument on the $f12 register
    swc1 $f12, 0($v0)

    # initalize the current node next value to null
    sw $zero, 4($v0)

    j end_insert_if_else

if_current_node_does_not_equal_null:
    # initalize the current node value to the passed in argument on the $f12 register
    swc1 $f12, 0($v0)

    sw $v0, 4($t1)
    sw $t0, 4($v0)

    j end_insert_if_else

end_insert_if_else:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

allocate_memory_for_node:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

    # allocate 12 bytes in memory for the new node
    li $v0, 9
    li $a0, 8
    syscall

    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

print_linked_list:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

    lw $s0, head # get a pointer to the head node
    lw $s0, 4($s0)

begin_loop_print_linked_list:
    # while (next != null)
    beqz $s0, end_loop_print_linked_list

    # get the value for the current node
    l.s $f12, 0($s0)

    # print out current item
    li $v0, 2
    syscall

    la $a0, end_line_prompt   #puts newlines in printed list
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    #get the pointer to the next node
    lw $s0, 4($s0)
    b begin_loop_print_linked_list

end_loop_print_linked_list:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

Comment: `c.lt.s $f12, $f0` looks like a `s`ingle-precision FP comparison for less-than.  Either reverse the order of the operands, or see if MIPS supports a `c.gt.s` instruction or something.

Comment: tried that already. I get an error when I change lt to gt or even ge, and it should be the same if I keep the lt and change the next line to bc1f, but I get "exception occured... bad address in data stack."

Comment: Did you try changing it to `c.lt.s  $f0, $f12`?  i.e. instead of changing `x < y` to `x >= y`, you're changing it to `y < x`.  But if the algo breaks with that change, then presumably there's another compare somewhere else.  Single-step the code in a debugger to find out what happens leading up to the exception.

Comment: It tells me the exception happens at sw $v0, 4($t1) in if_current_node_does_not_equal_null, but I don't see what's wrong here or just before.

Comment: Are you sure the original version was totally correct, and didn't just happen to work with certain starting register values?  i.e. maybe it depends on the value of an uninitialized register?  Or maybe sorting in the other order with the same starting list takes you to a corner case that didn't get before.

Comment: I'm fairly certain. I input my own values each time, and I've made sure to change it up with each test. If I can't get the insert part to be doing what I want, would it be possible to reversely print the list instead to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Printing a linked list in reverse order is inconvenient, unless it's doubly-linked.  The data structure itself only supports forward traversal, so reverse traversal requires a stack of some sort.  (e.g. a recursive function that prints the rest of the list *then* the current node).  IMO you should debug your algo with the compare reversed.  (Or wait for someone else to debug it for you and answer this question.)